# Python recursive find files and move to one destination directory

Tags: python, recursion, shutil

The script should recursively go through the rootpath directory and find all files with *.mp4 extension. Print the list of files with the directory structure. Then move the files to the destDir directory. The problem I run into is when trying to move the files to the new directory. Only files in the rootPath directory will be moved to the new destination. Files in subdirectories under rootPath causes errors:

```
/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST/level01_test.mp4
/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST/Destination/2levelstest02.mp4
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/HomeFolders/idmo04/Desktop/ScriptsLibrary/Python/recursive_find.py",     line 14, in <module>
    shutil.move(root+filename, destDir+'/'+filename)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/shutil.py", line 281, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/shutil.py", line 110, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/shutil.py", line 65, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:       '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST/Destination2levelstest02.mp4'
```

############## here is the script

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil

rootPath = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST/'
destDir = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/'


matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.mp4'):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
      print(os.path.join(root, filename))
      shutil.move(root+filename, destDir+'/'+filename)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations! You have already found `os.path.join()`. You even use it, on your `print` call. So you only have to use it with `move()`:

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(destDir, filename))
```

(But take care not to overwrite anything in `destDir`.)

Comment: I am getting there - I promise

Answer (score 2):

Change the `root + filename` in the last line to `os.path.join(root, filename)` (as seen two lines earlier)?

Comment: like so shutil.move(os.path.join(root, filename) - then I get syntax invalid?

Comment: shutil.move(ps.path.join(root, filename), destDir+'/'+filename) should work just fine.