# recursive find files with python

Tags: python, recursion, shutil

I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432197/python-recursive-find-files-and-move-to-one-destination-directory)
how to move all files recursively, but I would like to keep the same folder structure in the destination folder.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil

rootPath = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST/'
destDir = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/'


matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.mp4'):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
      print(os.path.join(root, filename))
      shutil.move(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(destDir, filename))
```

How is it possible to modify the above code to keep the same folder structure in the destination folder?

Comment: Is using mv out of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer assumes you're working in Python 2.x)

You need to make the sub-directories as you go:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil

rootPath = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST/'
destDir = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/'

matches = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.mp4'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        targetDir = os.path.join(destDir, root[len(rootPath):])
        if not os.path.exists(targetDir):
            os.makedirs(targetDir)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(targetDir, filename))
```

Also note that camelCase names are not standard practice in Python. Take a look at PEP8: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: In python3, `os.makedirs` includes a flag `exist_ok` that bypasses the race condition present here

Comment: @AdamSmith -- good point; I was assuming a Python 2.x scenario here.

Comment: just noticed the print(), so I guess it should have been Python 3 after all!

Answer (score 1):

To move all `.mp4` files from `root_dir` directory to `dest_dir` directory recursively while preserving the directory structure relative to `root_dir`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move

src = Path(root_dir)
dest = Path(dest_dir)
for file in src.rglob('*.mp4'):
    dest_file = dest / file.relative_to(src)
    try:
        dest_file.parent.mkdir(parents=True)
    except OSError:
        pass # ignore
    move(str(file), str(dest_file))
```

It uses [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library that is available in stdlib since Python 3.4. To install it on earlier versions:

```
$ pip install pathlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `os.system('your mv command')`?

Comment: Maybe independent of OS?